# How to use pull to refresh functionality in Android with dynamic TableLayout?

Tags: android, dynamic, tablelayout

I have created a dynamic TableLayout from data parsed from XML (via server).I want to implement pull to refresh functionality in TableLayout.

how can I implement it ? Any suggestions..?

Answer (score 0):

check out [this tool](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh).  FYI this question has already been asked a few times on stackoverflow, next time try a quick search before asking.

Comment: Already asked questions are about ListView and I want to implement that functionality in dynamic TableLayout.Now please give any suggestions..